# Is there the opportunity to search in a string with unknown letters?

Tags: python, string, indexing

I'm new in Python and trying to get the index number from a date out of a string.

For example my string is `"blablabladkalsjfd04.11.2019jkvlaö[…]"`

So I use `string.index()` but I need a solution that I can find different dates too.

It doesn't work with `string.index("*.**.20*")` (but I hope you know what I need.)

There could be everything before and after this piece but I need the index of this piece.

Comment: You need to use `re` for such situations.

Comment: Is the date always at the position 20?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import re

x = "blablabladkalsjfd04.11.2019jkvlaö"
print(re.search("\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}", x).start())
```

Output:

```
17
```

You could also get the whole index match:

```
x = "blablabladkalsjfd04.11.2019jkvlaö[…]"
y = re.search("\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}", x)
print(y.span())
```

Output:

```
(17, 27)
```